# Can not write to '/dev/tty' when build Docker images

Tags: docker, tty, dockerfile

I'm building docker images from Dockerfile and when I run a script(CUDA installation script) which has

```
echo XXX > /dev/tty
```

in it, then an error "/dev/tty: No such device or address" comes up and the build failed.
I've tried --silent flag but it seems do no help.

My base image is Cent OS 7.

Is there anyway to fix or work around this?

Comment: Did you see this: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2248801 ?

Comment: Try to share your host `/dev/tty` device by command:  `docker run --device /dev/tty your_image_name`  or if you can redirect output to stdout, stderr like  [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21787272/5189594)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've fixed this problem: it turns out I didn't install command tar & perl before hand.
And the script wants to write error messages to `/dev/tty`.
The error information led me to the wrong way to solve this issue.

Thanks.