# attach background process to /dev/tty from foreman's Procfile in during docker container launch

Tags: nginx, newrelic, dockerfile, foreman

Most of the questions dealing with `/dev/tty` and docker are centered around `docker run`.

I have a monitoring agent (`newrelic-nr-agent`, specifically) that must remain in the foreground in order to let `foreman` manage it.  When the script is invoked after the container has built and launched, everything's fine.  It would be best to launch the agent during the `docker-compose up` stage (which is how my containers launch) and not need to enter the running container to launch the agent.

I can't necessarily patch the script because it's installed from the New Relic apt repo.

I've looked at [build fails because `/dev/tty` isn't available](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32561121/can-not-write-to-dev-tty-when-build-docker-images) but that doesn't address my problem.  The image builds successfully but won't launch because the monitoring agent fails.

The relevant line in my Procfile:

`nginx-nr-agent: /usr/bin/nginx-nr-agent.py -f start`

And in the Dockerfile:

`# ENV TERM vt100
ENV TERM tty`

I've tried both settings individually *and* no setting.  None of the setting work.

The error from foreman:

`app_1 | 17:26:36 nginx-nr-agent.1 | Traceback (most recent call last):
app_1 | 17:26:36 nginx-nr-agent.1 |   File "/usr/bin/nginx-nr-agent.py", line 610, in <module>
app_1 | 17:26:36 nginx-nr-agent.1 |     main()
app_1 | 17:26:36 nginx-nr-agent.1 |   File "/usr/bin/nginx-nr-agent.py", line 583, in main
app_1 | 17:26:36 nginx-nr-agent.1 |     daemon_runner = MyDaemonRunner(app)
app_1 | 17:26:36 nginx-nr-agent.1 |   File "/usr/bin/nginx-nr-agent.py", line 521, in __init__
app_1 | 17:26:36 nginx-nr-agent.1 |     runner.DaemonRunner.__init__(self, app)
app_1 | 17:26:36 nginx-nr-agent.1 |   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/daemon/runner.py", line 80, in __init__
app_1 | 17:26:36 nginx-nr-agent.1 |     self.daemon_context.stdout = open(app.stdout_path, 'w+')
app_1 | 17:26:36 nginx-nr-agent.1 | IOError: [Errno 6] No such device or address: '/dev/tty'
app_1 | 17:26:36 nginx-nr-agent.1 | exited with code 1`

Answer (score 2):

For posterity, the solution:

In the Dockerfile:

`ENV TERM tty`

In the docker-compose.yml:

`tty: true`

In the Procfile:

`nginx-nr-agent: /usr/bin/nginx-nr-agent.py -f start`

The `tty: true` in the docker-compose.yml was the missing piece!

Comment: Man, I was having this problem for WEEKS. Google wasn't even helping, I finally used Duck Duck Go and searched for `nginx docker No such device or address` and found this obscure solution. Thanks for sharing with "posterity".

More specifically, my error was `nginx: [alert] could not open error log file: open() "/var/log/nginx/error.log" failed (6: No such device or address)` because I was running from a Node.js npm script in docker for development.

(I'm being explicit for for posterity as well)